# How to call manually onNext method in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I need help for `RxJava`.  Everything is working fine. But I want to call `onNext` manually in my other method.

```
    Observable<Data> mylist = Observable.fromIterable(datalist);                                                    
    mylist.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .buffer(6)
        .subscribe(new Observer<List<Data>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) { }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Data> list) {
                myadapter.addData(list);         
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {}

            @Override
            public void onComplete() { fetchNextPage(); }
        });
```

Like this:

```
OnloadMore() {

   onNext()  

}
```

Comment: its not very clear what you want to do here, since `onNext` is a callback to items being emitted from the upstream observable

Comment: It sounds like a [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html) is more appropriate here.

Comment: You need to use `Observable.create` or a `PublishSubject` or a `BehaviorSubject` then.

Comment: Observer emit items all at once. I want trigerr onNext event myself

Comment: It is still not clear what you are trying to do. Instead of showing us the code that doesn't work, maybe explain what you want to have happen.

Comment: observer emitting all item one time. How to make next emit with my click?

Comment: I want every 6 item add to myadapter with buffer operator in OnloadMore. But observer add all item one time like this 6+6+6+.....  No wait next OnloadMore method.   By the way my language not good. Sorry for that guys.